# Split array only when "," occurs

Tags: php

Is it possible to split this output everytime when "," is in fields 'code' and 'title?And put it in next index
like 7=>apartpark , 8=>dzielnica nadmorska. It is stored in variable and taken from database

[image]

```
$FiltersModel = new FiltersModel();
$listArr = $FiltersModel->getAllDesc($paramsArr);
$this->view->listArr = $listArr;
```

Its declared like this , i need to check whole $listArr before i pass it to the view

Answer (score 2):

Try the `<string>.split(',')` method

this methods splits the string at the given charakter (',') and return an array like:

```
$text = "hello,my,name,is,peter"

$parts = $text.split(',');
```

$parts[0] : "hello"

so your code:

```
if(count($yourarray[6]['code'].split(',') > 0)
//there is a comma in var
else
//there is no comma in var
```

Comment: Ok its nice but i need to check whole Array if something like this exists , and object is different for other users (array is diffent when other user is logged in and has his objects)